# Using -rpath and $ORIGIN with libtool-based projects?

Tags: c++, c, libtool, rpath

I am trying to incorporate a libtool-based package into a project of my own, perhaps in a non-standard way.  Here is my goal:

1. Build external project:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/blah --etcetera && make && make install
   ```
2. Build my own project which depends upon the external project's shared libraries and executables at runtime:

   ```
   gcc -I$HOME/blah/include -L$HOME/blah/lib -o $HOME/blah/bin/program
   ```
3. Package everything into a single "localized" tarball... that is, while I have everything in `$HOME/blah` on the build host I want the ability to extract the tarball to any arbitrary directory (on some other host) without having to futz with my environment.  The intent is to allow multiple versions of my project to coexist side-by-side without any nasty "cross-pollination".

I know that I can use `-rpath '$ORIGIN/../lib'` for my project to ensure that the right shared libraries always get loaded at runtime.  However, it seems that libtool insists on assigning its own `-rpath` setting based on the exact path of `$HOME/blah/lib`, which breaks if I happen to untar everything into a different directory (say, for example, `$HOME/blah.2011-06-02`).

Is there a way around this limitation?  I see a [rather lengthy rpath discussion between debian and libtool folks](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/1999/01/msg02245.html) on the topic, but it's somewhat old and inconclusive beyond "we disagree".

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Are you wanting to tarball your binaries, unpack them in an arbitrary location on the target host, and execute them?  You can use AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS to incorporate the other package into your own autoconfiscated package (I recommend against this), but this will only help with source distributions.  IMO, including dependencies in your own package is a mistake; dependency resolution is what package management systems are for, and you should not try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @William: package management systems generally require root privileges.  I would love to use a dependency-management tool that allowed me to set up my own repo without requiring any privilege escalation, but AFAIK that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the options presented here on [Rpathissue](http://wiki.debian.org/RpathIssue) on the debian Wiki, using [`chrpath`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/chrpath) in your 'install' step or some post-processing script sounds like a viable option. (It's available on a bunch of distros via your favorite package manager.)

It doesn't require patching `libtool` which is a plus IMO.

Note that it has some limitations: can only save the new `rpath` if it's shorter (or same length) as the original one.

The other (pragmatic) option is to remove the `rpath` (chrpath can do that), and just have a wrapper script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to whatever is necessary for your app. That has a chance of being slightly more portable too (if you handle the other shared library path environment vars some OSes have).